# config file that shared between the frontend and backend

Tags: reactjs, django, django-views

i need to write a config file to share with the frontend developer for common things like parameters name in requests.
for example in my view file, i have something like this:

```
class View(ApiView):
  def get(self,request):
    username = request.GET.get('phone')
```

i want to use a config file instead of hard coding phone.
and i want frontend(React) developer use this config too.(when they sending phone)

in other words, i want to extract the parameters name from a config file in the frontend and backend.

in other words, i want to extract the parameters name from a config file in the frontend and backend.